# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of MovieVersionEntity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

MovieEntity:

```
@Entity(name="MovieEntity")
@Table(name="Movie")
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="IsDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @Column(name="ModifiedDate")
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="MovieTypeId")
    private MovieTypeEntity movieTypeEntity;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="movieEntity",optional = false)
    private MovieVersionEntity movieVersionEntity;

    getter and setter methods
  }
```

MovieTypeEntity:

```
@Entity(name = "MovieTypeEntity")
@Table(name = "MovieType")
public class MovieTypeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="MovieTypeId")
    private int movieTypeId;

    @Column(name="Type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name="IsDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="movieTypeEntity",optional = false)
    private MovieEntity movieEntity;

    getter and setters.
}
```

MovieVersionEntity:

```
 @Entity(name = "MovieVersionEntity")
@Table(name="MovieVersion")
//@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MovieVersionEntity {

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="MovieId")
    private long movieId;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="MovieName")
    private String movieName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="DirectorName")
    private String directorName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="StopDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name="DoneWatching")
    private boolean doneWatching;

    @Column(name="WatchDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    //@CreatedDate
    private Date watchDate;

    @Column(name="ModifiedDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    //@LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="Id")
    private MovieEntity movieEntity;

    getter and setters
}
```

MovieRepository:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieEntity;

    @Repository
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public interface MovieRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<MovieEntity, Long> {

        @Modifying
        MovieEntity save(MovieEntity movieEntity);

        @Query("Select me.id from MovieEntity me inner join fetch me.movieVersionEntity as mve where mve.name = :name " +
                "and me.isDeleted = 0 and mve.endDate is null")
        long doesMovieExistWithName(@Param("name") String name);

        @Query("Select me from MovieEntity me inner join fetch me.movieVersionEntity as mve where me.id = :id and " +
                "me.isDeleted=0 and mve.endDate is null")
        Optional<MovieEntity> getMovie(@Param("id") long id);

        @Query("Select me from MovieEntity me inner join fetch me.movieVersionEntity as mve where me.isDeleted=0 and mve.endDate is null")
        List<MovieEntity> getMovies();
    }
```

MovieTypeRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieTypeEntity;
    @Repository
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public interface MovieTypeRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<MovieTypeEntity, Integer> {

        @Modifying
        MovieTypeEntity save(MovieTypeEntity movieTypeEntity);
    }
```

MovieVersionRepository:

package com.entertainment.entertainment.repository;

```
import com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieVersionEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface MovieVersionRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<MovieVersionEntity,Long> {

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieVersionEntity [Select me.id from com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieEntity me inner join fetch me.movieVersionEntity as mve where mve.name = :name and me.isDeleted = 0 and mve.endDate is null]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: name of: com.entertainment.entertainment.entity.MovieVersionEntity
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1805) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:505) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:660) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:942) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1283) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4696) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4166) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2131) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2056) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2056) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:810) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:605) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
```

I am not sure what is causing this error I tried debugging and going through the code again but no luck? It seems I have properly defined all the properties in the Entity class. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query for `doesMovieExistWithName` where clause has `mve.name = :name "`. But you have no attribute called `name` defined in `MovieVersionEntity`. I believe it should be `movieName`

Comment: I misread the exception, not knowing it was pointing to the property name.I appreciate your help. Do we have a plugin in INtellij which will highlight the sql syntax in Java and autoComplete for you? This was I can be sure I am not making an human mistake and the property does exist.

Comment: Sorry I did not get a chance to use IntelliJ Idea.